# MFC: CListView: Why SetItemState(-1, 0, LVIS_SELECTED) doesn't work if multiple items were selected with SHIFT + arrow key?

Tags: windows, listview, mfc, win32gui, virtuallistview

Easy to reproduce problem using default MFC dialog application:

1. Add listview control and link it to `CListCtrl` class - `m_listCtrl`.
2. Enable "owner data" or `LVS_OWNERDATA` flag to enable virtual list view mode. Enable multiple selection and "Always show selection".
3. In `OnInitDialog()` add at least one column and call `m_listCtrl.SetItemCount()` to set number of items in the list to more than one.
4. Link button click with a method that calls `m_listCtrl.SetItemState(-1, 0, LVIS_SELECTED);` That call should deselect all entries in the list.
5. Click on item in the list and use SHIFT + arrow key to extend selection to at least two entries. If selection is extended with mouse or CTRL + click or CTRL + SHIFT, then the issue doesn't appear.
6. Click on a button that triggers `SetItemState()` call in step (4) and notice that items don't get deselected the first time. They only get deselected the second time.

Is that a bug in listview control or am I doing something wrong?

Calling `m_listCtrl.SetItemState(-1, 0, LVIS_SELECTED);` should deselect all entries with the first call, but it does so only when called twice.

Comment: Can you do a small test? Temporarily change the control style to non-Virtual, add several items in the `OnInititDialog()` function and check if it works. The documentation about [Virtual List-view Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview#virtual-list-view-style) says that they do not store any information about their items, including state - especially check the **Compatibility Issues** section about the affected messages. You may have to implement it yourself, ie keep track of items' states using the callback mechanisms (notifications).

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Thank you for taking your time to reply. I did test with non-Virtual style and it works as expected - deselects all with first call. The relevant part from the MSDN documentation, I believe, is this part: 
"All four of the list-view styles—[...], —support the LVS_OWNERDATA style. List-view controls that have the LVS_OWNERDATA style do not store any item-specific information. Therefore, the only valid item state flags that you can apply to an item are LVIS_SELECTED and LVIS_FOCUSED. No other state information is stored".

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou This leads me to believe that selection and focus are (the only two item specific state information) stored for each item. Therefore selection and focus changing programmaticaly should work. And in fact does work, except for this little glitch that I've came across.

Comment: Aren't you miss a call to redrawing?

Comment: @sergiol Thank you for taking your time to reply. No, it's not a redrawing issue. LVN_ITEMCHANGED notifcation message is not being sent with the first call. It's sent with a subsequent call.